geoJSON административных единиц в России
Хочу выгрузить geoJSON'ы муниципальных образований в России – например, в Московской области их около 20. Формат geoJSON'a должен быть примерно следующим:

массив координат (точек) по границам мун. образования


Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Сейчас API Яндекс Карт не имеют возможности отображать регионы. А сохранение данных, получаемых через API, доступно только на расширенных коммерческих тарифах. Но скачать интересующую вас информацию возможности нет.
